# How can I reference an absolute symbol in an object file?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have compiled a jpg into an object file and am trying to reference it in my program. The symbol table is below:

```
user@host:~$ nm binary_artifacts.o 
000000000000ade3 D _binary_obj_jpg_end
000000000000ad00 A _binary_obj_jpg_size
00000000000000e3 D _binary_obj_jpg_start
user@host:~$
```

For the _binary_obj_jpg_start and _binary_obj_jpg_end symbols, it's pretty straightforward to use a char* to access them. However, the _binary_obj_jpg_size symbol is giving me some trouble.

I tried declaring it as:

```
extern const unsigned int const _binary_obj_jpg_size;
```

but I got segfaults when I used the symbol directly. I got the size correctly when I used it in my program as:

```
extern const unsigned int const _binary_obj_jpg_size;
printf("Size: %d\n", (int)&_binary_obj_jpg_size);
```

But this just seems wrong to declare it as an int and then take its address.

Is there a "more" correct way of doing this that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it - the object file doesn't really distinguish symbols as being "addresses" versus just "values". Indeed, to the linker, `_binary_obj_jpg_size` just looks like a variable at address `0xad00`, which causes the segfault. That's why you need to use its address.

Another way to think about it is that `_binary_obj_jpg_size` is effectively a difference of pointers (which is nominally `ptrdiff_t`) cast to a pointer. While such a conversion is valid, use of that pointer is undefined behavior. Casting back to an integer, however, is not.

To get around the "wrongness" of it, you can disguise it in a macro:

```
extern const void *_binary_obj_jpg_size; // note that the type doesn't really matter - only the address does
#define BINARY_OBJ_JPG_SIZE ((size_t)(uintptr_t)&_binary_obj_jpg_size)
```

Then, you can use `BINARY_OBJ_JPG_SIZE` naturally as the object's size.

Comment: Not the prettiest solution, but I guess that is the way it has to be!